# Adding content with existing installed module

Tags: 6

I have uploaded a Flipbook module designed for Drupal, and activated the module but can't find anywhere how I can insert that module (flipbook) content into a page.  It would be a simple shortcode with a wordpress plugin, but Drupal isn't that simple.  Can anyone give me an idea of how I can achieve this?  I basically want to create a page named "catalog" where it displays the flipbook module content which is a product catalog.   Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: **[Drupal 6 end-of-life announcement](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol)**

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I have 2 days remaining until EOL to get an answer that should be very basic to normal Drupal developers.  This Drupal site was migrated over from another company our client is no longer doing business with.  It will be converted to Wordpress, so it's pointless to upgrade for a month until the new site is launched.